# producer configuration of kafkamirrormaker2 strimzi

Tags: strimzi, apache-kafka-mirrormaker

i'm using kafka mirrormaker2 in order to copy topic content from Kafka's cluster A to Kafka's cluster B.
i'm getting the following  errors

***kafka.MirrorSourceConnector-0} flushing 197026 outstanding messages for offset commit (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask) [SourceTaskOffsetCommitter-1]***
where do i need to add the producer configuration ?

i tried to put it in 2 places but seems like it's not working:

kafkaMirrorMaker2:

```
 spec:
  config:
   batch.size: 9000
   offset.flush.timeout.ms: 3000
   producer.buffer.memory: 5000
instances:
 - enabled: true
  name: mirror-maker
  replicas: 3
  enableMetrics: true
  targetCluster: target-kafka
  producer:
    config:
      producer.batch.size: 300000
      batch.size: 9000
      offset.flush.timeout.ms: 3000
      producer.buffer.memory: 5000
  clusters:
    source-kafka:
      bootstrapServers: sourcekafka:9092
    target-kafka:
      bootstrapServers: targetkafka:9092
  mirrors:
    - sourceCluster: source-kafka
      targetCluster: target-kafka
      topicsPattern: "mytopic"
      groupsPattern: "my-replicator"
      offset.flush.timeout.ms: 3000
      producer.buffer.memory: 5000
      sourceConnector:
        config:
          max.poll.record: 2000
          tasks.max: 9
          consumer.auto.offset.reset: latest
          offset.flush.timeout.ms: 3000
          consumer.request.timeout.ms: 15000
          producer.batch.size: 65536
      heartbeatConnector:
        config:
          tasks.max: 9
          heartbeats.topic.replication.factor: 3
      checkpointConnector:
              config:
                tasks.max: 9
                checkpoints.topic.replication.factor: 3
  resources:
    requests:
      memory: 2Gi
      cpu: 3
    limits:
      memory: 4Gi
      cpu: 3
```

any idea where to locate the producer configuration ?

Comment: You should probably share the full custom resource and make sure it is properly aligned and formatted. The way you shared it above does not make it clear how does it look like.

Comment: added the full file.

Comment: Ok -> but that still looks very weird. There is no `instances` section. There is no `producer` section or `enableMetrics` field. The `targetCluster` field is for sure in a wrong place. So for a start, I think you should make sure it is a valid `KafkaMirrorMaker2` resource. You can check the docs: https://strimzi.io/docs/operators/latest/full/configuring.html#type-KafkaMirrorMaker2Spec-reference and the examples to check how it should look like: https://github.com/strimzi/strimzi-kafka-operator/tree/main/examples/mirror-maker

Comment: Thanks
instances is exist.
and the file is valid and works (without the producer properties).
thanks i will take a look on the links you attached.

Comment: Sorry, but no. There is no field `instances`. Definitely not in the _root_ of the YAML file. And this is not a valid Strimzi `KafkaMirrorMaker2` resource. It does not even have the `metadata` section or the `kind` and `apiVersion`.